# c++ method does not change the object field, which is standard container

Tags: c++

I have the code:

```
class OneChain {
public:
  std::vector<Cell> cellsChain;
  ...
  void removeIntersections( void )
  {
    for ( int i = 1; i < size(); i++ ) {
      if (
        (cellsChain[ i ].start >= cellsChain[ i - 1 ].start) &&
        (cellsChain[ i ].start < cellsChain[ i - 1 ].end)
      )
      {
        cellsChain.erase( cellsChain.begin() + i );
        i--;
      }
    }
    return;
  };
  ...
};

class OneLengthChains {
public:
  std::vector<OneChain> chainChains;
  ...
  OneLengthChains findNext( void ) {
    OneLengthChains ret;

    ret.setLength( chainLen + 1 );

    for ( int i = 0; i < size(); i++ ) {
      for ( int j = 0; j < chainChains[ i ].size(); j++ ) {
        OneChain ch = chainChains[ i ].findNext( j );

        if ( ch.size() < 2 ) {
          continue;
        }
        else {
          ret.add( ch );
        }
      }
      chainChains[ i ].removeIntersections();
    }
    clearOnes();

    return ret;
  };
  ...
};

class Chains {
public:
  std::vector<OneLengthChains> chains;
  ...
};
```

as you can see, the `OneChain::removeIntersections` method is called inside the `OneLengthChains::findNext` method. But intersectable elements of `OneChain::cellsChain` are still "on place", e.g. nothing happens. And if a call the `removeIntersections` explicitly like above, that's ok, intersectable elements removed from vector. What is the magic, that I do not understand?

```
void
findChains( Chains& chain, uint8_t * buf, uint16_t dataLen )
{
  OneLengthChains ch;
  int l = lMin;
  
  findFirstChains( ch, buf, dataLen, l );
  chain.push_back( ch );
  chain.push_back( ch.findNext() ); // removeIntersections() call nothing happens
  chain[0][0].removeIntersections(); // ok here
  
  chain.dump();

  return;
}
```

Comment: not sure but debug this part `cellsChain[ i ].start >= cellsChain[ i - 1 ].start) &&
        (cellsChain[ i ].start < cellsChain[ i - 1 ].end)`

Comment: You're right. I was debug this part and in debugger it's ok. But final result is nothing. As you can see the explicitly call the method is works fine, but calls method from method does not works.